# perl : unmatched ) in regex error

Tags: regex, perl

I'm no perl programmer, so I just need this simple script to run:

```
perl -e 'open(FILE,"tmp.plot"); my $seqLength = 643292; my $count=1; while(my $ln = <FILE>){ if( $ln =~ m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/ ) { if($1 > $count) { for($i = $count; $i < $1
; $i++){ print "0\n" } }; print "$2\n"; $count=$1+1;   }  } for($i = $count; $i <= $seqLength; $i++){ print "0\n" }' > dnaplotter.plot
```

the error is: 
`Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+) <-- HERE / at -e line 1.`

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!

TP

Comment: `-e` is usually reserved for one-liners. Why not save this to a script and run it with `perl scriptname`?

Comment: I don't get an error, nor do I see one.

Comment: I don't get an error either when running it on Perl 5.12.4.

Comment: That shell command does not cause Perl to emit the error you mention, at least not when run with `bash`.

Comment: No errors? Okay... Can you guys tell me how to check which version of perl I'm using on my Ubuntu? I'll try to run it as one liner

Comment: What shell? And that command what result in that error even for very old versions of Perl. (It's `perl -v`, as useless as the result will be.)

Comment: I'd rather you show us the exact screen output, incl both command and output.

Comment: yeah, seems to be... it's perl 5.14.2. Well, I don't know... what you mean run it with bash? In terminal?

Comment: command same as the one up. The output is: unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+) <-- HERE / at -e line 5

Comment: I'd rather you show us the exact screen output, incl both command and output.

Comment: This "terminal" is not a shell. You showed a shell command. What shell did you use to execute it? (`echo $SHELL`, perhaps?) I don't think it's a shell issue, but it's one of the very few possibilities if what you say is true.

Comment: @OgnjenSekulovic Do what ikegami is telling you and update your question, not repeat yourself in the comments.

Comment: `at -e line 5`???? You did not post 5 lines!

Comment: Properly formatted, that's a 16-line script. Why would you want to run it as a one-liner? Are you going to re-type the whole thing every time you run it? Is it embedded in a shell script? It's going to be a *lot* easier to deal with if you save it as an ordinary Perl script.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Not gonna help. (Maybe he's going to create an alias or a shell script. Or maybe it's just test code. You should see my answers, full of multi-line "one-liners", for that can demonstrate answers concisely. Same goes for questions.)

Comment: perl -e 'open(FILE,"tmp.plot"); my $seqLength = 4191338; my $count=1; while(my $ln = <FILE>){ if( $ln =~ m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/ ) { if($1 > $count) { for($i = $count; $i < $1
; $i++){ print "0\n" } }; print "$2\n"; $count=$1+1;   }  } for($i = $count; $i <= $seqLength; $i++){ print "0\n" }' > dnaplotter.plot

Comment: Huh, you can edit questions and answers years later?!?! Now go put the code you actually ran.

Comment: huh, no, again, this new code does not exhibit any such problem. Please update the **Question** with the code you actually ran, and please include the complete actual error message you received.

Comment: What's the output of `type perl`

Comment: ikegami, I think I just figured out this... Actually, I'm pretty embarrassed but I think I had a simple typo there with an extra "/" near the expression m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+) just after s+. I took your time for this. :((( I'm truly sorry

Comment: @ikegami: Conciseness loses its charm when I have to scroll sideways to see the whole "one-liner".

Comment: here, I made it a good and proper one-liner for you: `perl -le 'if (/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/ and $1 > ++$count) { print 0 for $count..643292; print $2 } END { print 0 for $count..643292 }' tmp.plot > dnaplotter.plot`

Comment: /scrolls down to see tidied version.  Ohhh.  Semantic changes owing to the terrible code prettifier I found which broke on `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program looks rather better laid out properly as a script. With `use strict` and `use warnings` it's fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FILE, "tmp.plot") or die $!;

my $seqLength = 643292;
my $count     = 1;

while (my $ln = <FILE>) {
    if ($ln =~ m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/) {
        if ($1 > $count) {
            for (my $i = $count; $i < $1; $i++) {
                print "0\n";
            }
        }
        print "$2\n";
        $count = $1 + 1;
    }
}

for (my $i = $count; $i <= $seqLength; $i++) {
    print "0\n";
}
```

Run it as

```
perl script.pl > dnaplotter.plot
```

Answer (score 4):

You are likely pasting in characters which are interpreted by the terminal software, hiding the command you actually ran.

For example,

```
$ echo -e 'm/^(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\x08)/' | od -c
0000000   m   /   ^   (   \   d   +   )   \   s   +   (   \   d   +   )
0000020  \b   )   /  \n
0000024

# Note the extra Backspace and ")" in the od output.

$ echo -e 'm/^(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\x08)/'
m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/

$ echo -e 'm/^(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\x08)/' | perl -c
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+) <-- HERE / at - line 1.
```